# asp.net mvc 3 Model with complex property and checkboxes

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a typed view as Item (one class that i created) with a form inside to add Items to my database. This Item class has one property called Categories that is a List (Category has 2 properties ID and Name)

Im using an editorfor in my view:

```
<div>
     @(Html.EditorFor(e => e.Categories, "Categories"))    
</div>
```

I created an EditorTemplatefor called "Categories.cshtml" render all the available categories:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}
@model List<Category>

@{
    foreach (Category category in ((BaseController)this.ViewContext.Controller).BaseStateManager.AvailableCategories)
    {
        @Html.Label("test", category.Name)
        <input type="checkbox" name="Categories" value="@(category.ID)" />
    }    
}
```

The checkboxes are well rendered (one for every Available category in cache), but after clicking in some, and post the form, im receiving my instance of Item but with the property Categories empty.

What i have to do to receive my List Categories completely instantiated after submit the form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont loop it. Let the framework generate the code for you (then, it will know how to build it back and bind it to your controller).

Just pass the list to the editor template and mvc will do the rest. Check my [blog post](http://www.shawnmclean.com/blog/2011/04/asp-net-mvc-multiple-check-boxes-in-an-array-or-list/) on something similar.

Comment: Thanks Shawn, really useful. I have a last doubt, i have to print in my case all Cached Categories. For Edit an item, i need to show all the categories from Cache but checked those that my Item has. How do you solve this? Thanks.Regards.

Comment: Create a view model that is going to be exactly whats going on the view. So the boolean property for the checkbox should already be processed before passing the model to the editor.

Answer (score 0):

Try using an index based loop.  This ensures MVC will render the item's attributes in such a way that allows the default model binder to instantiate the model on post back.  Also, use the Html helper for the checkbox as well:

```
var categories = ((BaseController)this.ViewContext.Controller).BaseStateManager.AvailableCategories;

for (var index = 0; index < categories.Count; index ++)
{
    @Html.Label("test", categories[index].Name)
    @Html.Checkbox("ID", categories[index].ID)
}
```

Comment: Hi Attadeini, thanks for the response. The items are rendered, but on postback i receive my model.Categories=null. Do you know why? Thanks.Jose